# Why does my input type="submit" work, but replacing it with button type="submit" not work?

Tags: html

I have a form:

```
<form method="post" action="https://' + site.txMainServer + '/' + location.storedUniqueId + '/txSpaceHandlerEntry" id="changeUserEmailForm">
... various fields ...
<input type="submit" name="submittedEmails" id="changeUserEmail_btn" value="Update emails/phone number settings">
</form>
```

That works fine. The form is submitted and the values get updated. The `site.txMainServer` and `location.storedUniqueId` references are just part of my server's object oriented database and the values are fine.

But if I just change

```
<input type="submit" name="submittedEmails" value="Update emails/phone number settings">
```

to a button like this

```
<button type="submit" name="submittedEmails" form="changeUserEmailForm">Update emails/phone number settings</button>
```

then the page reloads when the button is clicked, but the form is not submitted.

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn’t have a value at that point, which the backend probably checks for. Try `value="1"`. (For *identical* behaviour, `value="Update emails/phone number settings"`, but hopefully that’s not actually required.)

Comment: I also tried the same value parameter, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Is there JavaScript on the page that looks for an `input[type=submit]` and attaches listeners to that instead of a `submit` listener to the form?

Comment: No, there is no such JavaScript on the page. Is it needed? If so, I think I'll just stick with `input type="submit"`. The only reason I was trying to change it to a button was because I thought it would be easier to style the button. But I'm thinking it's maybe just as easy to style the plain old `input` tag.

Comment: It’s not that it’s needed, it would just explain the behaviour difference. Right now I’m not sure why they’d be different. (Also, IE doesn’t support `form` on `<input type="submit">` either.)

Answer (score 0):

The `<button>` tag `form` attribute does not work in internet explorer. Using it in another browser such as chrome or edge works.

Comment: I was testing with Chrome. But if it doesn't work in IE I think I will abandon this idea and just use `input type="submit"` which works.